# A png file is 404 error at GitHub Project Pages

Tags: github, http-status-code-404

I have a png file on gh-pages branch at Github, but I can't retrive it at GitHub Project Pages.
What's problem?

By the way the other files are fine at github pages.

https://github.com/ShawnHuang/GoogleDrive-API/blob/gh-pages/images/2f8db055.google-drive-logo-tiny.png

http://shawnhuang.github.io/images/2f8db055.google-drive-logo-tiny.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**http://shawnhuang.github.io** is a GitHub Pages website generated from the **https://github.com/ShawnHuang/shawnhuang.github.com** repository. This is a **[User Pages repository](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#user--organization-pages)**.

As such the following url http://shawnhuang.github.io/images/pattern.png will in fact display the image located at https://github.com/ShawnHuang/shawnhuang.github.com/blob/master/images/pattern.png

**[GoogleDrive-API](https://github.com/ShawnHuang/GoogleDrive-API)** is a different repository and, as such, won't be embedded by the **[Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)** generation process.

Three solutions come to mind:

- **You want to keep the logo under the GoogleDrive-API:** Just link to it using an absolute href to https://github.com/ShawnHuang/GoogleDrive-API/blob/master/images/2f8db055.google-drive-logo-tiny.png
- **You'd prefer to use a relative link:** Move or copy the logo in the **[images](https://github.com/ShawnHuang/shawnhuang.github.com/tree/master/images)** folder of the shawnhuang.github.com repository
- **Leverage the existing http://shawnhuang.github.io/GoogleDrive-API/ GitHub [Project pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#project-pages) website:** From your **http://shawnhuang.github.io** site, link to the https://github.com/ShawnHuang/GoogleDrive-API/blob/gh-pages/images/2f8db055.google-drive-logo-tiny.png image.